# Microservices Strategy for handling foreign keys / EF Core 6 cross-database queries

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, database-design, entity-framework-core, microservices

We have some applications written in .NET 6.0 and using Entity Framework Core 6.

These applications consume data from SQL Server databases. Each application has its own database, and these databases are on a single SQL Server instance.

Recently, we needed to create a new database containing Postcodes, Streets, Neighborhoods and Cities around the world. This data is well normalized in a unique database.

To meet a new requirement, we will need to store this new data (actually, only the foreign keys) across the databases. For example: A user from the application "x" will store his city. In practice, this city is foreign key containing his `CityID` guid (that comes from an external database).

We understand that direct database calls across the databases is an anti-pattern, that's why we are looking for alternatives for this case.

Micro services architecture suggests that each application should handle its own data, but unfortunately, there is no way to handle foreign keys.

We found in our research to solve this case:

- A SQL Server view that represents external data and foreign keys.
- Services loosely coupled for the postcodes. Each client database will store these IDs, but there will be no foreign keys check and enforce.
- Triggers for data replication across databases

Does anyone have a tip for this scenario with the best practices?

Thank you.

Comment: Triggers for data replication across databases? No, no, no, no... You are falling into the trap of "secretly connecting the databases behind the scenes"; if you do this, why don't you better add the FKs altogether? In µs architecture, the replication should be done using the service API each service provides; That's it! No other connections. Design you API correctly.

Comment: And data replication, whether driven by the APIs themselves, a Service Bus or at the database level is common in Microservice Architecture.  If you decide that Service A needs a copy of data belonging to Service B, that's fine.  But it should consume a change event feed, or use data replication to build an eventually-consistent view of the other Service's data.